# Could we find the overall force and direction of something with a diagram only? (i.e. no calculation)

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors, free-body-diagram

My friend, who is a geologist, and I were just debating some dynamics stuff.

To make this easier, lets come up with an analogy......lets say there's a boat and it's being pulled by two smaller boats in a north east direction. The top boat is pulling at 400kN and the bottom boat at 300kN.

If I were working this out by calculation, it becomes obvious that I'd quickly resolve the forces into their components, get the resultant force in order to get the overall force and direction etc.

BUT. We just wondered if it were possible to do this with a diagram only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes : see Parallelogram of Forces.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LYXGlXMi6_c

Comment: Many thanks for this link sammy gerbil! Just to clarify, overall force and resultant force are the same thing, they're synonymous right?

Comment: Physicists use the synonymous terms net force and resultant force, but not overall force.  Whether overall force means the same depends whether you are referring to the vector sum of the other forces.